# Illuminate \ Http \ Exceptions \ PostTooLargeException No message laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8

I have post section in my application .
I want to add video on my post while it was uploading the video this error will occur 
Tips: I have modified php.ini but still having this error how to solve this error i appreciate any suggestion please help!

post_max_size = 1024M
upload_max_filesize = 1024M

PostController.php

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
use Auth;
use DB;
use App\Post;
use App\Category;
use App\Subcategory;
use Image; 

class PostController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $page_name = 'Posts';   
        if (Auth::user()->type === 1 || Auth::user()->hasRole('Editor') || Auth::user()->hasRole('Master Admin')) { 
           $data = Post::with(['creator'])->orderBy('id','DESC')->get(); 
        }else{
            $data = Post::with(['creator'])->where('created_by', Auth::user()->id)->orderBy('id','DESC')->get();
        }
        return view('admin.post.list',compact('data','page_name'));
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
         $page_name = 'Create Post';
        $categories = Category::where('status',1)->select('name','id')->get(); 
        return view('admin.post.create',compact('page_name','categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request) //with this request we can pass the title , slug ... all fields
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
          'title'=>'required',
          'short_description'=>'required', 
          'description'=>'required', 
          'category_id'=>'required',
          'subcategory_id'=>'required',
          'img'=>'required',  
      ],[

        'title.required' => "The Title Field is Required",
        'short_description.required' => "The Short Description Field is Required",
        'description.required' => "The Description Field is Required",
        'img.required' => "The Image Field is Required",
        ]);

     $post = new Post();  // using Post Model to all the below fields can connect with Post Table in database
     $post->title = $request->title;
     $post->slug = str_slug($request->title,'-'); //title will be updated with this title name separated with -
     $post->short_description = $request->short_description;
     $post->description = $request->description;
     $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
     $post->subcategory_id = $request->subcategory_id;
     $post->status = 1;
     $post->hot_news = 0;
     $post->view_count = 0;
     $post->main_image = '';
     $post->thumb_image = '';
     $post->list_image = '';
     $post->created_by = Auth::id(); //who created this post brings by ID
     $post->save();
     $file = $request->file('img');
     $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension(); 
     $main_image = 'post_main_'.$post->id.'.'.$extension; 
     $thumb_image = 'post_thumb_'.$post->id.'.'.$extension; 
     $list_image = 'post_list_'.$post->id.'.'.$extension;
     Image::make($file)->resize(653,569)->save(public_path('/post/'.$main_image)); 
     Image::make($file)->resize(360,309)->save(public_path('/post/'.$list_image));
     Image::make($file)->resize(122,122)->save(public_path('/post/'.$thumb_image));
     $post->main_image = $main_image; 
     $post->thumb_image = $thumb_image;
     $post->list_image =  $list_image;
     $post->save();
     return redirect()->action('Admin\PostController@index')->with('success','Post Created Successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $page_name = 'Edit Post';
        $post = Post::find($id);
        $categories = Category::where('status',1)->select('name','id')->get(); 
        return view('admin.post.edit',compact('page_name','post','categories'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
         $this->validate($request,[
          'title'=>'required',
          'short_description'=>'required', 
          'description'=>'required', 
          'category_id'=>'required',
          'subcategory_id'=>'required',

        ],[

        'title.required' => "The Title Field is Required",
        'short_description.required' => "The Short Description Field is Required",
        'description.required' => "The Description Field is Required",
        'img.required' => "The Image Field is Required",
        ]);

     $post = Post::find($id);
    if($request->file('img')){
        @unlink(public_path('/post/'.$post->$main_image)); 
        @unlink(public_path('/post/'.$post->$thumb_image));
        @unlink(public_path('/post/'.$post->$list_image));
        $file = $request->file('img');
     $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
     $main_image = 'post_main_'.$post->id.'.'.$extension;
     $thumb_image = 'post_thumb_'.$post->id.'.'.$extension;
     $list_image = 'post_list_'.$post->id.'.'.$extension; 
     Image::make($file)->resize(653,569)->save(public_path('/post/'.$main_image));
     Image::make($file)->resize(360,309)->save(public_path('/post/'.$list_image));
     Image::make($file)->resize(122,122)->save(public_path('/post/'.$thumb_image));
     $post->main_image = $main_image;
     $post->thumb_image = $thumb_image;
     $post->list_image =  $list_image;
   }
     $post->title = $request->title;
     $post->slug = str_slug($request->title,'-');
     $post->short_description = $request->short_description;
     $post->description = $request->description;
     $post->category_id = $request->category_id;
     $post->subcategory_id = $request->subcategory_id;
     $post->save();
     return redirect()->action('Admin\PostController@index')->with('success','Post Updated Successfully');
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        $post = Post::find($id);
        @unlink(public_path('/post/'.$post->$main_image));
        @unlink(public_path('/post/'.$post->$thumb_image));
        @unlink(public_path('/post/'.$post->$list_image));
        $post->delete();
        return redirect()->action('Admin\PostController@index')->with('success','Post Deleted Successfully');
    }



     public function status($id){
       $post = Post::find($id);
       if ($post->status === 1) {
            $post->status = 0;
        }else{
             $post->status = 1;
        }
          $post->save();
          return redirect()->action('Admin\PostController@index')->with('success','Post Status Changed Successfully');
    }


     public function hot_news($id){
       $post = Post::find($id);
       if ($post->hot_news === 1) { 
            $post->hot_news = 0;
        }else{
             $post->hot_news = 1;
        }
          $post->save();
          return redirect()->action('Admin\PostController@index')->with('success','Post Set As Hot News Changed Successfully');
    }


 public function subcategories()
    {

       $category_id = Input::get('category_id');
      $subcategories = Subcategory::where('category_id', '=', $category_id)->where('status',1)->get();
      return response()->json($subcategories);
    }

}
```

**list.blade.php**

```
  @extends('admin.layout.master')
  @section('content')


    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('admin/assets/css/lib/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css ') }}">
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap-select.less"> -->





  <div class="breadcrumbs">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="page-header float-left">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <h1>{{ $page_name }}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <div class="page-header float-right">
                    <div class="page-title">
                        <ol class="breadcrumb text-right">
                            <li><a href="/back">Dashboard</a></li>

                            <li class="active">Posts</li>
                        </ol>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content mt-3">
            <div class="animated fadeIn">
                <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="card">

                 @if($message = Session::get('success'))
                 <div class="alert alert-success">

                  {{ $message }}

                 </div>

                 @endif

                        <div class="card-header">
                            <strong class="card-title">{{ $page_name }}</strong>
     @permission(['Add Post','All'])              
 <a href="{{ url('/back/posts/create') }}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Create</a>            @endpermission

      @permission(['Add Post','All'])              
 <a href="{{ url('/back/comment') }}" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin-right: 5px;">All Comments</a>            @endpermission
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                  <table id="bootstrap-data-table" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                    <thead>
                      <tr>
                        <th>#</th>
                        <th>Image</th>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Author</th>
                         <th>Total View</th>
                         <th>Status</th>
                         <th>Hot News</th>
                         <th>Options</th>
                      </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                      @foreach($data as $i=>$row)
                      <tr>
                        <td style="width: 5%; text-align:center;">{{ ++$i }}</td>
                        <td style="text-align:center;"> 
                 @if(file_exists(public_path('/post/').$row->thumb_image)) 
                 <img src="{{ asset('post') }}/{{ $row->thumb_image }} " class="img img-responsive"> 

                 @endif 
                        </td> 
                        <td  style="width: 13%; text-align:center; ">{{ $row->title }}</td>  

                        <td style="width: 5%; text-align:center;"> {{ $row->creator->name }} </td> <!-- use this method bring name in users table -->

                        <td style="width: 5%; text-align:center;">{{ $row->view_count }}</td>

                      <td style="width: 10%;"> 
                     {{ Form::open(['method'=>'PUT','url'=>['/back/post/status/'.$row->id],'style'=>'display:inline' ]) }}
                     @if($row->status === 1)
                       {{ Form::submit('Unpublish',['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) }}
                       @else
                       {{ Form::submit('Publish',['class'=>'btn btn-success']) }}
                     @endif
                       {{ Form::close() }}

                         </td>      

                        <td style="width: 5%"> 
                     {{ Form::open(['method'=>'PUT','url'=>['/back/post/hot/news/'.$row->id],'style'=>'display:inline' ]) }}
                     @if($row->hot_news === 1)
                       {{ Form::submit('No',['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) }}
                       @else
                       {{ Form::submit('Yes',['class'=>'btn btn-success']) }}
                     @endif
                       {{ Form::close() }}

                         </td>       


                        <td>
                          @permission(['Add Post','All','Post Update']) 
           <a href="{{ url('/back/comment/'.$row->id) }} " class="btn btn-info">Comment</a>  
             <a href="{{ url('/back/post/edit/'.$row->id) }} " class="btn btn-primary">Edit</a>
           @endpermission
           @permission(['Delete Post','All']) 
           {{ Form::open([
            'method'=>'DELETE',
            'url'=>['/back/post/delete/'.$row->id],
            'style'=>'display:inline',
            'onsubmit' => 'return confirmDelete()' 
             ]) }}
           {{ Form::submit('Delete',['class'=>'btn btn-danger']) }}
           {{ Form::close() }}
           @endpermission

                         </td>

                      </tr>
                      @endforeach
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>


                </div>
            </div><!-- .animated -->
        </div><!-- .content -->




    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/plugins.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/main.js') }}"></script>

<script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/datatables.min.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/dataTables.buttons.min.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/buttons.bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/jszip.min.js') }}"></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/pdfmake.min.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/vfs_fonts.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/buttons.html5.min.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/buttons.print.min.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/buttons.colVis.min.js') }} "></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('admin/assets/js/lib/data-table/datatables-init.js') }} "></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#bootstrap-data-table-export').DataTable();
        } );
    </script>




<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function confirmDelete(){

     var conform = confirm("Are You Sure To Delete?");
     if (conform)
       return true;
     else
       return false;
     }

</script>





@endsection
```

Comment: are you using `php artisan serve` ?

Comment: @ChristopheHubert yes i'm using php artisan serve

Answer (score 5):

`php artisan serve` uses the php.ini from `php/cli` (usually in `/etc/php[version]/cli`)

Update this file accordingly:

```
post_max_size = 1024m
upload_max_filesize = 1024m
```

Comment: This answer is a lifesaver.

Comment: Where can I find /etc/php[version]/cli on my computer on Windows11?

Answer (score 1):

`post_max_size` represents the size that comes in the post body meaning the size is the aggregation of all fields' size containing in the request body. So `post_max_size` must be greater than `upload_max_filesize` (the addition of all uploads' size) + data containing in other fields in the request body.

`post_max_size` doc says:

> Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file
>   upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than
>   `upload_max_filesize`. Generally speaking, `memory_limit` should be larger
>   than `post_max_size`.

See in details [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size). Refer to [Payload Too Large](https://httpstatuses.com/413) also.

Comment: It says "  Unsupported image type. GD driver is only able to decode JPG, PNG, GIF or WebP files.  "

Comment: @Andria Well, that's another issue. That's not related to request body payload.

Comment: @Andria you should open another question for that issue and describe the issue clearly there. If my answer satisfies your current issue you should mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache server just try to some changes in php.ini like this

post_max_size = 1024m
upload_max_filesize = 1024m